# Suggested way to do a 'parallel period' SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I want to get the profit between two dates. Then I can do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Profit)
FROM Sales
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-01' AND <other_filters>
```

I would then like to compare it to a previous period offset by a fixed amount. It could be written something like this to get it in two rows:

```
SELECT SUM(Profit)
FROM Sales
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-01' AND <other_filters>
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Profit)
FROM Sales
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND '2014-02-01' - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND <other_filters>
```

Is there a way to do this without a union? I am looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
    SELECT SUM(Profit),
    ???
FROM Sales
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-01' AND <other_filters>
```

I think the tricky part here is how to 'un-do' the where filter for the offseted-time calculation.

Comment: Depending on how much analytics you are doing, and how complex your business calendar is, you'll probably eventually need to find that you need to implement a calendar table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and `OR` the range checks in the `WHERE` clause (unless they are subsequent in which case you can combine them directly of course).

```
SELECT sum(CASE
             WHEN date >= '2014-01-01'
                  AND date < '2014-02-02' THEN
               profit
             ELSE
               0
           END),
       sum(CASE
             WHEN date >= '2014-01-01' - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
                  AND date < '2014-02-02' - INTERVAL 1 YEAR THEN
               profit
             ELSE
               0
           END)
       FROM sales
       WHERE date >= '2014-01-01'
             AND date < '2014-02-02'
             OR date >= '2014-01-01' - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
                AND date < '2014-02-02' - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
```

Note: Prefer not to use `BETWEEN` here but check for a right half open range check. That way, if the precision of `date` changes, records on the end past midnight are still in the results.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Could you explain a bit more about using `BETWEEN` vs the `[start, end)` range instead? Also, don't you mean right-half open range ( `<` being the end date) ?

Comment: @David542: Example: If you have `date BETWEEN '2021-11-01' AND '2021-01-30'` and for what ever reason the precision of `date` is increased, to also include the time of the day (or you "recycle"  the query for another table where the date also has a time portion but miss this) only 2021-01-30 00:00:00 will match the expression, even 2021-01-30 00:00:01 won't. And you're right about the wrong side, I indeed meant right open. I've edited the answer.